# Вывод массива объектов в twig

Tags: php, symfony2, foreach, twig

Пытаюсь вывести массив в twig.

Исходный объект out:

```
 +"expression": "{36521}=1 and {36522}>8000000"
+"issue": ">80% утилизация вход GigabitEthernet0/0.204"
+"lastchange": 0
+"status": 0
+"priority": 2
+"triggerid": "30233"
+"ack": "0"
 +"functions": array:2 [▼
1 => {#1076 ▼
  +"function": "str"
  +"parameter": "Tunnel,#1"
  +"functionid": "36521"
}
2 => {#1077 ▶}
]
}
```

Нужно вывести массив functions, который содержит в себе два объекта.

Код twig:

```
 .. <tr>

                <th>Function ID</th>
                <th>Function</th>
                <th>Parameter</th>

            </tr>

                    {% for functions in out %}
            <tr>


                <td>{{ functions.1.functionid }}</td> {#здесь пытался по другому #}
                <td>{{ functions.functionid }}</td>
                <td>{{ functions.function }}</td>
                <td>{{ functions.parameter }}</td>


            </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Банально не выводит.
Что может быть не так?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так

```
{% for number in functions %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ loop.index0 }} - {{ number.function }}</td> 
        <td>{{ loop.index0 }} - {{ number.parameter }}</td>
        <td>{{ loop.index0 }} - {{ number.functionid }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```